# How to filter for measurement before and after a certain date

Tags: r, date, filter, longitudinal

I am trying to create a subset, using filter, in which I have subjects with at least one anthropometric measurement (variable named zbfa) before and one measurement after a certain date (variable named dat_mov). Part of the longitudinal dataset looks like this:

```
id <- c(12)
periode <- c(2011:2018)
timepoint <- c(1:8)
zbfa <- c("NA", "NA", "-0.36", "-0.47", "NA", "-0.70", "NA", "NA")
dat <- c("NA", "NA", "2013-10-10", "2014-09-22", "NA", "2016-12-05", "NA", "NA")
dat_mov <- c("NA", "NA", "NA", "2014-06-30", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")
data <- data.frame(id, periode, timepoint, zbfa, dat, dat_mov)
```

```
 id periode timepoint  zbfa        dat    dat_mov
1 12    2011         1    NA         NA         NA
2 12    2012         2    NA         NA         NA
3 12    2013         3 -0.36 2013-10-10         NA
4 12    2014         4 -0.47 2014-09-22 2014-06-30
5 12    2015         5    NA         NA         NA
6 12    2016         6 -0.70 2016-12-05         NA
7 12    2017         7    NA         NA         NA
8 12    2018         8    NA         NA         NA
```

So in the example above, for id 12, I have different timepoints. I aim to select, among all subjects in the dataset, only those IDs that have available data for zbfa right before dat_move (last measurement before this date) and after dat_mov (the first measurement six months after dat_mov).
I tried using `new_data <- data %>% filter(dat < dat_mov)` in order to first filter the IDs with measurement before dat_mov and then filter those with measurement after dat_mov, however when using this code, R returns a subset filtering for dat and dat_move in each row. So, id 12 (as shown in the example) would not be maintained, since dat > dat_move in the specific timepoint of dat_move.
My desired output, in a different dataframe, would look like this for id 12 (only timepoint 4 and timepoint 6):

```
 id periode timepoint  zbfa        dat dat_mov
1 12    2013         4 -0.36 2013-10-10      NA
2 12    2016         6 -0.70 2016-12-05      NA
```

I hope I was clear enough.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please see this post to edit your question so the community can answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Monnomcjo! Thank you for the tip. I hope my question is clearer now after my edit!

Comment: @SarahWarkentin Thanks for the additional information, but it might help to clarify further. Why is timepoint 4 (row 4) not included? Did you want to exclude if `dat_mov` in the same row? If there are multiple dates before but *not* after the `dat_mov` how would you handle? Exclude all rows for that `id`? It might help further if you could expand your example with a few different `id` cases, with different dates, and show what the output might be in those cases.